Is there a concentration inequality for the quantum gate fidelity $F(C,U)$ for a channel $C$ such that $\int dU F(C,U)=X$?
For a fixed quantum channel $N$ and a unitary channel $U$, we define $N$'s gate fidelity as
$$ F(N,U) = \int \langle \psi| U \, N(| \psi \rangle \langle \psi |) \, U^\dagger| \psi \rangle d\mu_H(\psi)$$
where $\mu_H$ is the Haar measure over $d$-dimensional states. Suppose that for some channel $C$ you know that
$$ \int F(C,U) d\mu_H(U) = X $$
where this time $\mu_H$ is the Haar measure over the $d$-dimensional unitary group. Can we say something about the concentration of $F(C,U)$ around the mean $X$? I tried using Levy's lemma to derive a concentration inequality for $f(U) = F(C,U)$, but I was not able to find a suitable upper bound to the Lipschitz constant of $f$. To avoid misunderstandings, by Lipschitz constant I mean the smallest $L$ such that
$$ |f(U) - f(V)| \leq L \|U-V\|_2 $$
Any ideas?

Isn't the first integral independent of $U$? Writing $|\psi\rangle$ as $V|0\rangle$ with the integral being over the Haar-random $V$ and then using the invariance of the Haar measure by unitary transformations? That would give you that $F(C, U)$ is constant w.r.t. $U$, so the average is easily computed. Or did I miss something?

I already know the average $X$ from previous calculations. My goal here is to upper bound the probability that $|F(C,U) - X| > \epsilon$ for a generic $\epsilon$

My point is that we would then have $F(C,U)=X$ for a fixed $C$ and for all $U$.

I don't think the first integral is independent of $U$. Invariance of the Haar measure allows us to absorb $U$ into $|\psi\rangle$ at the output of the channel, but it pops back up at the input. Also, $F(U, U)=1$ and $F(D, U)=1/d$ where $D$ is the completely depolarizing channel.

One approach would be to get rid of the first integral using Horodecki's formula \begin{align}
F(N, U)=\frac{dF_e(N, U)+1}{d+1}
\end{align}
where entanglement fidelity is defined as
\begin{align}
F_e(N, U)=\langle\psi|(I\otimes U^\dagger N)(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)|\psi\rangle
\end{align}
with $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i|i\rangle|i\rangle$ before trying to find a concentration inequality.

I agree with @AdamZalcman. Using the invariance of the Haar measure we would still have $N(V | 0 \rangle \langle 0 | V^\dagger)$ inside the integral, and there's no way to get rid of it. As for Horodecki's formula, I tried that too, but with little success. The best upper bound that I was able to find with this strategy is $L<\sqrt{d}$, which is not useful since in Levy's lemma the upper bound is $exp(-\frac{d}{L^2} \epsilon \cdot K)$ for a known constant $K$.

Indeed, I should have carried the computations out, my bad!

This function seems like it should be 1-Lipschitz. How hard have you tried to bound $L$?

I did as suggested by Adam Zalcman. By definition $| F_e(N,U) - F_e(N.V)|= Tr[| \psi \rangle \langle \psi | ( I \otimes U^\dagger N | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | - I \otimes V^\dagger N | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | ) ]$. Since $F_e(C) = \frac{1}{d^2} \sum_i |Tr[K_i]|^2$, where ${K_i}$ is a Kraus decomposition of channel $C$, one can rewrite the equation as $\frac{1}{d^2} \sum_i | |Tr[U^\dagger K_i|^2 - |Tr[V^\dagger K_i|^2 | =  \frac{1}{d^2} \sum_i | |Tr[U^\dagger K_i| - |Tr[V^\dagger K_i| | \cdot  | |Tr[U^\dagger K_i| + |Tr[V^\dagger K_i| | $.

@JohnWatrous One can bound $||Tr[U^\dagger K_i|-Tr[V^\dagger K_i|| \leq |Tr[U^\dagger K_i-Tr[V^\dagger K_i|$. Using the inequality $|Tr[AB]| \leq |A|1 |B|\infty$ we further upper bound $ |Tr[U^\dagger K_i-Tr[V^\dagger K_i^\dagger| \leq |K_i^\dagger|1 |U^\dagger - V^\dagger|\infty \leq \sqrt{d} |K_i^\dagger|_1 |U^\dagger - V^\dagger|_2$. I am basically stuck here. I don't know how to get rid of the $| |Tr[U^\dagger K_i^\dagger]| +|Tr[V^\dagger K_i^\dagger]| |$
P.S. In my previous comment $K_i$ should be  $K_i^\dagger$. I fixed this here, but can no longer edit the old comment

The function described in the question is 1-Lipschitz. To argue this, we'll get an inequality in place before we start writing integrals.
If  $\vert \gamma\rangle$ and $\vert\delta\rangle$ are unit vectors, then the operator $\vert\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma\vert - \vert\delta\rangle\langle\delta\vert$ has at most two nonzero eigenvalues: $\pm\sqrt{1 - \vert\langle \gamma\vert \delta\rangle\vert^2}$. We can therefore bound the $\infty$-norm of this operator in terms of the Euclidean norm for vectors like so.
$$
\bigl\| \vert\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma\vert - \vert\delta\rangle\langle\delta\vert\bigr\|_{\infty}
= \sqrt{1 - \vert\langle \gamma\vert \delta\rangle\vert^2}
= \sqrt{1 + \vert\langle \gamma\vert \delta\rangle\vert}
\sqrt{1 - \vert\langle \gamma\vert \delta\rangle\vert}\\
\leq \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1 - \operatorname{Re}(\langle \gamma\vert \delta\rangle)}
= \bigl\| \vert\gamma\rangle - \vert\delta\rangle\bigr\|
$$
(You often see a related bound for the trace norm rather than the $\infty$-norm, for which we pick up an additional factor of 2, but we're going to be interested in the $\infty$-norm instead.)
In particular, taking $\vert\gamma\rangle = U \vert\phi\rangle$ and $\vert\delta\rangle = U\vert\phi\rangle$ for any unit vector $\vert\phi\rangle$ gives this:
$$
\bigl\| U \vert\phi\rangle\langle\phi\vert U^{\dagger} - V \vert\phi\rangle\langle\phi\vert V^{\dagger} \bigr\|_{\infty} \leq 
\;\bigl\| U \vert\phi\rangle - V\vert\phi\rangle\bigr\| \leq \| U - V\|_{\infty}.
$$
The $\infty$-norm is (like all norms) convex, so by thinking about the spectral decomposition of a given density operator we see that the same bound works for density operators:
$$
\bigl\| U \sigma U^{\dagger} - V \sigma V^{\dagger} \bigr\|_{\infty}
\leq \| U - V\|_{\infty}.
$$
That's the inequality we needed. Now, observing that $N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert)$ is a density operator for every unit vector $\vert\psi\rangle$, we get what we're after:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bigl\vert f(U) - f(V) \bigr\vert & =
\;\Biggl\vert \int \langle \psi \vert 
U N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) U^{\dagger} - V N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) V^{\dagger}
\vert\psi\rangle\,
\mathrm{d}\psi
\Biggr\vert\\
& \leq
\int \bigl\vert \langle \psi \vert 
U N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) U^{\dagger} - V N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) V^{\dagger}
\vert\psi\rangle
\bigr\vert\,\mathrm{d}\psi\\
& \leq
\int \bigl\| 
U N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) U^{\dagger} - V N(\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert) V^{\dagger}
\bigr\|_{\infty}\,\mathrm{d}\psi\\
& \leq \int \| U - V\|_{\infty}\, \mathrm{d}\psi\\
& = \| U - V\|_{\infty}
\end{aligned}
$$
Of course you can further upper-bound this by $\|U-V\|_2$ if you wish, and we find that the function is 1-Lipschitz as claimed.

The answer is concise and impeccable. Thanks a lot for the time and effort you must have put into it!
